# Prepared SQL Statements INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently following W3Schools tutorial with Prepared SQL statements, When I try to insert data into the database it's saying $firstname = "Nathan" and $lastname = "Kent" is an unused local variable? Also it returns no error so it's connecting fine and when I check the database it has no new entries.

```
 function setData(){
    global $servername;
    global $username;
    global $password;
    global $dbname;

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } else{
         echo "Connection Successful" . "<br>";
   }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test(firstname, surname) VALUES       (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $surname);

    $firstname = "James";
    $lastname = "Williams";
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New Records Created";

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}
```

Comment: Where is `$firstname` and `$surname` defined?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I am pretty sure you need to set them before binding; and there is the issue of `$**sur**name` vs `$**last**name`.

Comment: @Uueerdo I've corrected that, That was a last minute change ;)

Comment: @Uueerdo Not according to the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Script47 I thought that too? But W3Schools shows it differently :/

Comment: it returns no errors because you're not checking for any. mysqli defaults to failing by returning boolean false, not throwing exceptions. Since you don't check any of your return values, you're just ASSUMING it worked.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is why I said I wasn't sure, I know php like to handle it's variables in strange manners.

Comment: @MarcB my debugging was based on... Changing $surname in the bind_param() this caused it to fail, but returning the value to the correct way it returned no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MYSQLI you actually need to look for errors rather than assuming they will shout at you.

```
function setData(){
    global $servername;
    global $username;
    global $password;
    global $dbname;

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else{
         echo "Connection Successful" . "<br>";
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test(firstname, surname) VALUES (?,?)");

    // add error check
    if ( $stmt === false ) {
        echo $conn->error;
        exit;
    }

    // Its not necessary to load the variables before the `bind_param`
    // but as you dont actually have these variables yet you do
    $firstname = "James";
    $lastname = "Williams";

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $surname);

    $status = $stmt->execute();

    // add error check
    if ( $status === false ) {
        echo $conn->error;
        exit;
    }


    echo "New Records Created";

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}
```

You could clean this up a bit as well by connecting to the database in the mainline code and passing the connection param to the function as well as the data parameters

```
function setData($conn, $firstname, $lastname){

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test(firstname, surname) VALUES (?,?)");

    // add error check
    if ( $stmt === false ) {
        echo $conn->error;
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $surname);

    $status = $stmt->execute();

    // add error check
    if ( $status === false ) {
        echo $conn->error;
        exit;
    }

    return "New Records Created";

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}


$servername = '127.0.0.1';
$username   = 'root';
$password   = 'veryStRongPassPhrASe';
$dbname     = 'mydatabase';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else{
     echo "Connection Successful" . "<br>";
}


$msg = setData($conn, 'Fred', 'Bloggs');
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Instead of `echo $conn->error; exit;` why not just `exit($conn->error);`?

Comment: @Script47 You say potato I say potato. Actually that does not work in writing. hahhaa

Comment: Awesome! I will use that in the future, I figured out its because i've used global variables in my function so the other values have to be in the same scope. Is a global variable the correct way to retrieve dbconfig details? I have the dbconfig details in another .php file and then including it.

Comment: Well personally I would connect to the database in the mainline code and pass the `$con` variable to a function if it needed the connection

Comment: @RiggsFolly pawtato potaato?

Comment: @Script47 I tend to do that as in real life I would not be echoing the errors to the browser, but instead writing them to an error log somewhere only I can see what a silly billy I have been

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's the method I originally tried but $conn-> wasn't readable in my function for some strange reason. I still have a lot to learn on scope in PHP, it's mind boggling :D

Comment: It soon becomes second nature! But we all make mistakes so dont let it worry you

Comment: There you go, I added another option for coding the connection in the main line code and passing it and the data as parameters

Answer (score 0):

You do not define a value for `$surname`:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $surname);

$firstname = "James";
$lastname = "Williams";
$stmt->execute();
```

Change `$lastname` to `$surname`